# Intellij IDEA - Compile grails project with -source 1.8 (or 1.7)

Tags: grails, groovy, intellij-idea, javac

The groovy compiler complains when running `run-app` in Intellij:

```
(...)
.Error 
|
Compilation error: startup failed:
Compile error during compilation with javac.
(...).java:42: error: multi-catch statement is not supported in -source 1.6
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException | SAXException | IOException e) {
                                              ^
  (use -source 7 or higher to enable multi-catch statement)
1 error


1 error

Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
(...)
```

I have tried all the settings I found or read that could affect it:

- Project Settings -> Module -> Dependecies
  [image]
  [image]
- Project Settings -> Module -> Sources
  [image]
  [image]
- Project Settings -> Project
  [image]
- Project Settings -> SDKs
  [image]
- Settings -> Compiler -> Java Compiler
  [image]
- BuildConfig.groovy
  [image]
- pom.xml
  [image]
- Run Configuration
  [image]
  [image]

What else could I try?

Comment: have you also checked `grails.project.(target|source).level` in `BuildConfig.groovy`?

Comment: @cfrick amazing, that does the job! Thanks! Promote it to an answer to get the credits :).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the `BuildConfig.groovy` are also settings for the target/source level.  To my understanding they are the sole authority for setting it (well the starting JDK should be able to handle it).

```
grails.project.target.level = 1.8
grails.project.source.level = 1.8
```

Both values are generated by default in a new grails project (at least since 2.X)